# Converting SQL Decimal Date to DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS format

Tags: sql, date, decimal, sql-convert

I have a date/ time field in my database with the type set to 'decimal'.

When querying the date/ time field using the below query:

```
SELECT my_date_time_field
FROM my_table
```

It returns the following result (an example):

```
1323977278
```

This is meant to represent the following date and time (UK date format):

```
30/11/2011 02:50:19 AM
```

I have been told that the result I get from the database is how many seconds have passed since:

> 01-JAN-1970 00:00:00

I would like to know how I can get my SQL query result to display the date in the proper UK date format.

I have tried the following and it did not work from a similar question:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(my_date_time_field AS VARCHAR(8)), 112)
```

Should I be converting **my_date_time_field** to the **YYYYMMDDHHMMSS** format first before doing a **DATEDIFF** function?

Or is there a function(s) to convert **my_date_time_field** straight to a **DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS** or **DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS** format?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using (which is presumably SQL Server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the value to a `datetime` using:

```
select dateadd(second, 1323977278, '1970-01-01')
```

You can then format this however you like using `convert()` or `format()`.

Comment: But when you format this value like this `CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(SECOND,1323977278,'19700101 00:00'), 131 )` (131 for UK format) weird but it returns `20/01/1433  7:27:58:000PM `

Comment: @sarslan 131 code uses gregorian calendar thus pretty much messing it all up! :)

Comment: Thank you! This converts the result to: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000.

Comment: @DidarCern . . . It converts the value to a `datetime` value.  That is *presented* in that format.  To get a specific format, use `convert()`.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

Although the explanation below would be best, for SQL 2008 I would go with:

```
SELECT  
CONCAT (CONVERT(VARCHAR, dateadd( S, 1323977278, '1970-01-01'), 103), ' ',  
CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(dateadd( S, 1323977278, '1970-01-01') AS TIME),100))
```

It would be handy to create a function since I'm sure you'll need it often.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Decimal_To_Date (
@ctimestamp BIGINT
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
  declare @return datetime

  SELECT @return = FORMAT(CAST(dateadd( S, @ctimestamp, '1970-01-01') AS DATETIME),'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm tt')

  return @return
END
GO
```

Then just use it as

```
SELECT dbo.Decimal_To_Date(1323977278)
```

and you'll get 15/27/2011 07:27 PM

ultimately (if you don't want a function) just use:

```
FORMAT(CAST(dateadd( S, 1323977278, '1970-01-01') AS DATETIME),'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm tt')
```

PS: Format will work from SQL Server 2012. If you have a previous version you'll need to use CONVERT

PS2: The 131 code uses Hijiri (Gregorian) calendar which is not what you want...

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunately I do not have authority to CREATE functions in this server. I will however pass this on as it will be useful!

Comment: Just use FORMAT(CAST(dateadd( S, 1323977278, '1970-01-01') AS DATETIME),'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm tt')

Comment: I am running from SQL Server 2008.

So I used the CONVERT function. This is how it looks:

convert(datetime, cast(dateadd(second, [SUBMIT_DATE], '1970-01-01') as datetime), 113)

But it still displays the date/ time in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000' format.

I also tried 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm tt' (as you mentioned above), but it returns the following error:

Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 3 of convert function.

I tried changing my CONVERT and CAST functions to return VARCHAR but it still returns the same error message. But of course, I am after a DATETIME data type.

Comment: SELECT  CONCAT (CONVERT(VARCHAR, dateadd( S, 1323977278, '1970-01-01'), 103), ' ',  CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(dateadd( S, 1323977278, '1970-01-01') AS TIME),100))

Comment: I tried this and it works, but the data type of this field changes and I need it to be a DATETIME data type.

Thank you, Carlos :)

Comment: DATETIME format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000. Either you want a DATETIME or a format of DATETIME